# What is my crontab -e local file path? I want to set it via BASH script

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, bash, cron

In my Ubuntu, my username is "meuser". When i do crontab -e, i can setup my rules. But instead of doing it with crontab -e, how can i do it directly to a file? Which file i cant modify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting crontab's [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/crontab.1.html):

> There    is    one   file   for   each   user's   crontab   under the
>          /var/spool/cron/crontabs directory. Users are not allowed to  edit  the
>          files  under  that directory directly to ensure that only users allowed
>          by  the  system  to  run  periodic  tasks  can  add  them,   and   only
>          syntactically correct crontabs will be written there.  This is enforced
>          by having  the  directory  writable  only  by  the  crontab  group  and
>          configuring  crontab  command with the setgid bid set for that specific
>          group.

So you can't directly edit this file in a script (without sudoing around the restrictions). But, what you *can* do is the following: Just create a crontab file somewhere in the filesystem and then use

```
crontab <filename>
```

to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type in `sudo crontab -e` in the command line. The in the editor that pops open, hit the `i` key to insert in the cron that you want to add. I had to do this for my feedafever.com installation on jamescampbell.us/fever and it worked great running it from my ubuntu server instance on amazon ec2.